# Cordova android VideoPlayer plugin not works

Tags: cordova, android-video-player

Im upgrade the cordova version of my app to cordova@5.0.0 ,in that app have FileOpener which is deprecated at cordova 3.0.
Then I try use the VideoPlayer plugin as follows:

I used this in Video.html page

```
<body onload="onLoad()">    
<a href="#" onClick="playVideo('file:///android_asset/www/videos/introduction/stroke.mp4');" rel="external">What is Stroke?</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/video.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoad() {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }
    function playVideo(vidUrl)
    {
    console.log("here");
        window.plugins.videoPlayer.play(vidUrl);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

But I don't have plugins.xml in my res/xml folder, rather I have config.xml file, so I placed the below in config.xml (which is in this path - platforms/android/res/xml)

```
<plugins>
<plugin name="VideoPlayer" value="com.phonegap.plugins.video.VideoPlayer"/>
</plugins>
```

Then I create a directory "phonegap/plugins/video" in this folder "src/com/" and move VideoPlayer.java into it.

When I run this in my local machine, it shows the error -
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.plugins.videoPlayer') and the video also not works.

Note: I follow the [installation steps on  this page](http://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer).

Please advise me what I did wrong in this and how I solve this.